# Most efficient way to merge two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, algorithm, merge

I've already solved this out. However I'm looking for a faster solution since my variables has thousands of objects.

I have two arrays like this:

```
var full = [{a:'aa1',b:'bb1'},{a:'aa3',b:'bb2'},{a:'aa3',b:'bb3'},{a:'aa2',b:'bb3'}],
some = [{a:'aa1',b:'bb1'},{a:'aa3',b:'bb3'}];
```

I'm trying to **flag** in a new attribute called `c` in `full` if the object exist on some. Expected result:

```
 [{a:'aa1',b:'bb1',c:true},{a:'aa3',b:'bb2'},{a:'aa3',b:'bb3',c:true},{a:'aa2',b:'bb3'}]
```

Some important tips:

- some always has less elements than full
- both arrays are sorted equal

My current approach is:

```
var getIndexByAB = function(arr, a,b){
     var initialIndex =  getIndexByAB.initialIndex || 0,
     len = arr.length;
     for(initialIndex; initialIndex < len ;initialIndex++ ){
         var el = arr[initialIndex];
         if( el.b === b && el.a === a ){
             getIndexByAB.initialIndex = initialIndex;
             return initialIndex;
         }
     }
     return -1;
}

var len = some.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len ; i++){
 var el=some[i],
 index = getIndexByAB(full,el.a,el.b);
 if(index > -1) full[index].c = true;
}
```

**UPDADE**: original solution improved using Juan comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are sorted, you can just pass an index to start the search from, that will avoid the O(n^2). You were already doing it, but by storing the index in a global variable. Instead, you should pass it as an argument to `getIndexByAB`.

```
function getIndexByAB(arr, a,b , initialIndex){
    // Was tracking last index by storing it in a global 'this.initialIndex'. 
    // 'this' points to 'window' in global functions. That's bad, it 
    // means this function can't be called on different arrays without
    // resetting the global 

    // var initialIndex =  this.initialIndex || 0,

    initialIndex = initialIndex || 0;
    var len = arr.length;
    for(initialIndex; initialIndex < len ; initialIndex++ ){
        var el = arr[initialIndex];
        if( el.b === b && el.a === a ){
            // Bad globals
            // this.initialIndex = initialIndex;
            return initialIndex;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

var len = some.length;
var lastValidIndex = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < len ; i++){
    var el = some[i];
    // Pass the index here, so it doesn't start from scratch
    var index = getIndexByAB(full, el.a, el.b, lastValidIndex);
    if(index > -1) {
        full[index].c = true;
        lastValidIndex = index;
    }
}
```

By the way, if you do want a function to cache some values, here's how to do it avoiding globals. (Not that you should use it in this case)

```
var getIndexByAB = (function(){
     // This will only be executed once, and is private
     // to getIndexByAB (all invocations)
     var lastGoodIndex = 0;

     return function(arr, a,b, resetIndex){
         if (resetIndex) {
            lastGoodIndex = 0;
         }

         var len = arr.length;
         for(var index = lastGoodIndex; index < len ; index++ ){
             var el = arr[index];
             if( el.b === b && el.a === a ){                 
                 lastGoodIndex = index;
                 return index;
             }
         }
         return -1;
    };
})();
```

Alternatively, you could achieve the following by caching it in `getIndexByAB.initialIndex` but it's not very elegant. The main reason for avoiding this is the fact that `getIndexByAB.initialIndex` can be modified by anybody else

Comment: You only removed one usage of `this`.

Comment: @jrajav Thanks, fixed it.... Actually, the code was already saving the current index using a global variable `this.currentIndex`. That was pretty bad, therefore, this is the same code, without relying on a global variable. Which means that it can now be called on multiple arrays, multiple times

Comment: Thanks Juan, I understand your point of globals. I though that this.XXX works as an attribute of the function, I had been using this to save function cache for many time. However, I cant understand why you are passing "i" to getIndexByAB insted "index". It suppose that index will grow faster than i.

Comment: @MartinBorthiry That was incorrect, I should have been passing the last value of `index`, fixed it

Comment: What if I replace `this.initialIndex` by `getIndexByAB.initialIndex` in my original approach ? should it works ?

Comment: @MartinBorthiry Yes, it will work, but your solution already worked. I don't think it's a good solution. I've provided a more elegant solution that would allow you to do the same thing

Comment: ok, thanks, I accepted your answer. But, it is no clear for me this assignation `initialIndex = initialIndex;` :-/

Comment: @MartinBorthiry There, I had made another mistake, fixed it now!

Answer (score 0):

Since the arrays are both sorted and `some` is strictly smaller than `full`, you could save some time by traversing both arrays at the same time with different indexes. As it is, you are traversing `full` to get the index of the matching element each time, so you have **O(N^2)** running time, but you only need to continue the search from the last element you matched.

Comment: Let me know if you need me to make it any clearer or give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Not as efficient as @Juan's answer (which takes advantage of the sorted nature, among other things), but I thought I'd still present my solution as it incidentally forced me to come up with a solution for cloning and comparing Javacript objects.

#### Utilities

```
// Create a copy of x without reference back to x
function clone(x){
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
}

// Pass any number of arguments of any type. Returns true if they are all identical.
function areEqual(){
  for(var i = 1, l = arguments.length, x = JSON.stringify(arguments[0]); i < arguments.length; ++i){
    if(x !== JSON.stringify(arguments[i])){
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

#### Flagging function

```
// Your flagLabel being 'c'
function matchAndFlagWith(flagLabel,aFull,aSome){
  var aFlagged = clone(aFull);

  for(var i1 = 0, l1 = aSome.length, oSome; oSome = aSome[i1], i1 < l1; ++i1){
    for(var i2 = 0, l2 = aFlagged.length, oFlagged; oFlagged = aFlagged[i2], i2 < l2; ++i2){
      if(areEqual(oFlagged,oSome)){
        oFlagged[flagLabel] = true;
      }
    }
  }

  return aFlagged;
}
```

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/barney/p2qsG/